# VHDL: Optmize signal comparisons for synthesis

Tags: fpga, vhdl, xilinx, synthesis, asic

As a preface, there are certain coding styles used in VHDL/Verilog which help the synthesis tools infer different hardware(some better in perfomance than the other). For example using an if-else-if ladder would infer a series of mux'es whereas a case statement would infer a single wide multiplexer. These coding styles are not significant when doing only functional simulation, but substantial when targeting the RTL for ASIC or FPGA implementation. In case of FPGAs the CLB(configurable logic block) architecture defines the capabilities achieved using RTL(like the LUT input width).

Coming to the Question, I have seen many instances where two n-bit wide signals might have to be compared in VHDL. And I need some advice on the hardware inference. I will use the following code snippet to further narrow the question.

```
signal counter_a: unsigned(31 downto 0);
signal counter_b: unsigned(31 downto 0);
signal clk, trigger_en, count_b_en : std_logic;

counter_a_gen: process (clk) begin
    if(rising_edge(clk)) then
        counter_a <= counter_a + 1; -- free running counter
    end if;
end process;

counter_b_gen: process (clk) begin
    if(rising_edge(clk)) then
        if(count_b_en = '1') then
            counter_b <= counter_b + 1;
        else 
            counter_b <= (others => '0');
        end if;
    end if;
end process;

-- compare the counters to generate some logic
trigger_gen: process (clk) begin
    if(rising_edge(clk)) then
        if(counter_a = counter_b) then
            trigger_en <= '1';
        else 
            trigger_en <= '0';
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

The above snippet has two 32 bit counters counter_a and counter_b, which have to be compared in a sequential block. If I consider a 4-input LUT in an FPGA, the comparison would need multiple levels of logic. Such a path would be make it hard to meet timing because of the huge combinatorial delays. So my question is how do we make it optmized? In this case to increase the perfomance?

Comment: *a case statement would infer a single wide multiplexer.* Only if you add the **parallel case** synthesis directive. Default it is also treated as if-then-else-if.

Comment: May be. But I guess synthesis tools should also be intelligent enough to infer parallelism in circuits based on user specified directives/constraints rather than RTL attributes.

Comment: I would expect the tools to place the logic such that it can use a high speed carry chain so it may not be as bad as you think. Another possibility is to tweak things to get the tool to utilise whatever sort of DSP block your part comes with, device dependent code, but the DSP48E1 for example has magnitude comparison as one of its 'ALU' party tricks, you could probably get one of the counters out of the same block.  If you need ultimate speed you generally have to write at least somewhat to the part you are targeting.

Comment: How do we infer dsp elements from coding styles? Or do we need to manually instantiate the element for comparison?

Comment: Xilinx Tools don't use carry chains in that case. The [PoC Library](https://GitHub.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC) offers several IP cores that perform better than standard synthesis.

Comment: A 32 bit comparison takes only 11 LUT4 and has a depth of 3. This is very fast.

Comment: Here the comparison is on two 32 bits. So I guess 21 LUT4s and still 3 levels of logic. Does it make sense?

Comment: And when does Xilinx use carry chains? For example in case of arithmetic operations right?

Answer (score 2):

- If your circuit can support delays to the trigger_en signal, you can split the comparison (for example 4 8 bits comparators) and pipeline the result over several cycles.
- You can use several comparators in parallel with future values, keeping counter_a+1, counter_b+1,counter a+2, counter a+3... pipeline the result of each comparator (as above), then decide which comparison is valid from the value of count_b_en during the last 2 or 3 cycles. Lots of hardware !

"Huge combinatorial delay" : It really depends on your target frequency. FPGAs have fast carry propagation and direct paths between adjacent LUTs, so the delays are not very large for 32bits comparators. (128 bits is a large comparator, 32bits is quite narrow)

The suggestion above with lots of hardware may be theorically faster but practically slower sometimes because the additional hardware add propagation delays, signal load...

Comment: I agree that FPGAs have fast carry chains but still the propagation delay added by these elements are significant when the fpga target frequency is is greater than 250 MHz. As I see the best method might be to split the comparisons across multiple clock cycles.

Comment: Another addition: If I were comparing a counter to a static value, things would have been much easier. I could start the counter from (static value - 1) and count down to -1. This way a single bit MSB comparison can be used instead of 32 bit wide comparison. I wanted to know if something similar could be done here.